# Check if there is space in specific range of indexes in a line in a file and replace the space with 0

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have the following issue which I am facing. I have several lines in a file and I have an example shown below.
The values between position 4-10 can contain any combinations of values and spaces and it has be replaced with 0 only if it is an empty space.

```
#input.txt

014       789000
234455    899800    
1213839489404040
```

In the example line above, we can see that we have empty spaces between position 4-10. This position to check is fixed. I want to be able to check if every line in my file has empty spaces between position 4-10, and if there is empty space, I want to be able to replace it with 0. I have provided below the desired output in the file.

```
#desired output in the input.txt

0140000000789000    # note that 0 has been added in the position 4-10
2344550000899800    # # note that 0 has been added in the position 7-10
1213839489404040
```

I was able to do the following in my code below. The code below is only able to add values at specified position using the sed command and I want to be able to modify this code such that it can do the task mentioned above.

May someone please help me ?

My Code:

```
#append script
function append_vals_to_line {
    insert_pos=$(($1 - 1))
    sed -i 's/\(.\{'$insert_pos'\}\)/\1'$2'/' "$3"
}

column_num_to_insert="$1"
append_value ="$2"
input_file_to_append_vals_in ="$3"

append_vals_to_line "$column_num_to_insert" "$append_value" "$input_file_to_append_vals_in"
```

Comment: yes that is possible to. Any combinations of spaces and values can be between position 4-10 and only if the index has space, then replace it with 0.

Comment: Assuming the trailing blanks at the end of the 2nd input line are a typo, `tr ' ' 0 < file` is all you need to get the expected output you provided from the sample input you provided so if that's NOT all you need then [edit] your question to contain more tru;y representative sample input/output including cases that doesn't work for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest an `awk` solution for this:

```sh
awk '{s = substr($0, 4, 7); gsub(/ /, 0, s); print substr($0, 1, 3) s substr($0, 11)}' file

#input.txt

0140000000789000
2344550000899800
1213839489404040
```

A more readable version:

```sh
awk '{
   s = substr($0, 4, 7)
   gsub(/ /, 0, s)
   print substr($0, 1, 3) s substr($0, 11)
}' file
```

This command first gets a substring from 4th to 10th position in variable `s`. Then using `gsub` we replace each space with a `0` and finally we recompose and print whole line.

---

Consider this `awk` command that takes start and end position from arguments:

```sh
awk -v p1=4 -v p2=10 '{
   s = substr($0, p1, p2-p1+1)
   gsub(/ /, 0, s)
   print substr($0, 1, p1-1) s substr($0, p2+1)
}' file
```

Comment: `substr($0, 4, 7)` means start at 4th position and get 7 characters so it will grab positions `4-10`

Comment: for instance if I have to read at positions 147-170, then would it be awk '{
   s = substr($0, 147, 24)
   gsub(/ /, 0, s)
   print substr($0, 1, 146) s substr($0, 170)
}' file

Comment: yes that's almost correct. It would be: `print substr($0, 1, 146) s substr($0, 171)`

Comment: One last question. for instance if the line extends all the way to position 465, then it would be ``` awk '{ s = substr($0, 147, 24) gsub(/ /, 0, s) print substr($0, 1, 146) s substr($0, 465) }' file ```  as  substr($0, 465) } just added the ```s``` to the remaining values. This is the confusion I had, may you please clarify?

Comment: Total line length doesn't matter because `substr($0, 171)` will get substring from `171st` position to the end position. See updated answer where you can just pass start and end positions in command line argument and awk will get it right for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
awk '
/[[:blank:]]/{
    sub(/[[:blank:]]*$/,"")   # remove trailing spaces if any
    gsub(/[[:blank:]]/,"0")   # replace each /[[:blank:]]/ with "0"
} 1' file
```

Alternatively, you can do:

```
awk '
length($2) {
    $0=sprintf("%s%0*d",$1,16-length($1),$2)
} 1' file
```

Either prints:

```
0140000000789000
2344550000899800
1213839489404040
```